# How to tell to <input type=password>ConfirmationPassword</input> when it can be :valid AFTER it is = to <input>Password

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have stuck with this. Just can't find how to manipulate JS and trick validation.

I wanna to trigger this - onkeyup when `<input2 pwd>` which is = to `<input pwd>`

```
.l_input:valid + span::after {
position: absolute;
content: '✓';
color: #009000;
font-size: 1vw;}
```

And this is my supper duper js

```
var check = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('password').value == document.getElementById('c_password').value) {
      document.getElementById('validity').is(':valid'); //FORCE :VALID
  } else {document.getElementById('validity').is(':invalid');   // :INVALID 
}}  // 'validity' is span
```

Now css triggers after any symbol (coz it doesnt have pattern)

HTML:

```
<input onkeyup="check()" type=password id=password placeholder='Password'>
<input onkeyup="check()" type=password id=c_password placeholder='Confirmation Password'>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the relevant HTML so we can see a working example of the issue. I would also suggest editing the question to make the problem and your goal much clearer, as right now it's not obvious exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please don't add solution in question. Please add an answer with what worked explaining what changes you made.

Comment: remove solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
function check() {
            if (document.getElementById('password').value == document.getElementById('c_password').value) {
                document.getElementById('c_password').setCustomValidity('');
            } else {document.getElementById('c_password').setCustomValidity('Not matching');   }
            }
```

This ^ JS makes `document.getElementById('c_password') <INPUT>` Invalid until i say.

In this way CSS `:valid // :invalid` works the way i SET IT.

Which is less coding just few additional lines.

NOTE ! :

```
setCustomValidity('') // no string = valid
setCustomValidity('Not matching') // string is not displayed
```